# basis of the ordering of list returned by component.find()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce-id, find

I am using `component.find(aura_id)` to get the component. I have multiple components with the same aura_id So I am getting a list.

My question: What is the basis of the ordering of list returned by `component.find()`?

Comment: I think it should be same as you are seeing in the UI.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am observing different behavior.

Comment: Ideally you should not be dependent on the ordering of component retrieved by `component.find`.

Comment: I have two UI component returned by component.find().
In which at the place of the first UI component I am creating a new component and the previous one is destroyed.
But In the list returned by component.find() the newly created UI component is at index 1. which should be at index 0 by the order in which we are seeing.
The old component has been moved to index 0 from 1.

Comment: If you have destroyed the old one then you won't get that on the list returned by `component.find`.

Comment: I have destroyed the old component but at the same location(in UI) I have created a new component and this new component is not at the index in the list when the destroyed component was.

Comment: Relying on undocumented ordering would be very risky. Add an explicit attribute to the component to encode the information you need and so tell the difference between the instances.